# Python: assign to sys.argv item, and use it further

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Script 'top.py' makes use of another script 'myScript.py' by passing an argument to it. Script 'myScript.py' contains:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    sys.argv[1] = myObject
    sys.argv[1].functionSpecificToMyObject() # works as expected
```

The use is achieved in 'top.py' by simply calling 'myScript.py' with an argument 'myHelperArgument'. However, in top.py I cannot make use 'myHelperArgument'. Is this possible? If not, any suggestion on a possible solution (given the intention above) is welcome. Of course, I prefer not to write to a file and read later.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). This is designed to use objects defined in one Python source file (module) in another.

Create two files in the same directory:

First file `my_lib.py`:

```
def my_func():
     return 42
```

Second file `my_script.py`:

```
import my_lib

print(my_lib.my_func())
```

Now, `python my_script.py` in the same directory shows `42`.